# How can I make docker-machine create a VM in a specific location

Tags: docker

My development machine is a laptop with a smallish SSD and a huge external disk. Ideally I'd like docker-machine to use the external drive rather than filling up my internal disk.

I know that I can hack it with mounts and so on but is there a way to make the docker-machine command use a directory that I specify instead of defaulting to `~/.docker/machine/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried this option `-s, --storage-path` "Configures storage path [$MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH]"?

You can see it in docker-machine --help.

Comment: Thanks, that looks right. I'd been using `docker-machine help create` and there was just so much detail I couldn't see it.

Comment: For anyone interested, the way you use `--storage-path` is like this: ` docker-machine -s "D:\Docker\.docker\machine" create --driver=virtualbox default` . Note that any *future* `docker-machine` commands *also* need to include the `-s` flag.

Comment: If you don't want to use the flag for every command, you can set the `MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH` environment variable.