# Move boot2docker and .docker folder in other drive

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm new in docker. I have installed docker in windows in the D drive but the Boot2docker VM is in the user folder in the C drive.

I dont have enough space in the C and the boot2docker is growing when i pull softwares from the docker hub.

So I want to move the boot2docker or the .docker folder in the D drive.

Is it possible ? and how can i do ?

Comment: What version of docker are you using? Are you using docker-machine?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Moving existing disk**

The big size for the VM machine is `.vmdk` or `.vdi`, so you just need to move the disk to Drive D instead of moving whole `.docker` directory.

What you can do in simple way in Oracle VirtualBox Manager GUI:

1. Stop the `boot2docker` VM, and find the place `disk.vmdk` under
   **Setting->Storage**
2. Copy the `disk.vmdk` to Disk D (any place)
3. Detach (-) the `disk.vmdk` in VirtualBox Manager
4. Attach (+) the new `disk.vmdk` from Disk D. make sure the SATA port number is the same
5. Verify the boot2docker env, if not, try to find the reason
6. Remove the `disk.vmdk` in Disk C to save space if migration is finished.

It shall work as I am always lack of disk space and move those disks around

**For new created disk**

Normal it will create to your use default user directory, but it is possible to redirect to new place by using flag `--storage-path` during creation

```
$ docker-machine --storage-path f: create -d virtualbox dev
```

see related questions in [How can I make docker-machine create a VM in a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016261/how-can-i-make-docker-machine-create-a-vm-in-a-specific-location)

Comment: Hi, I found the files you mentioned in C:\Users\USERNAME\VirtualBox VMs\boot2docker-vm directory. Do I copy the .vbox file as well?

Comment: Failed to open the hard disk file D:\Docker\boot2docker-vm\boot2docker-vm.vmdk.

Cannot register the hard disk 'D:\Docker\boot2docker-vm\boot2docker-vm.vmdk' {9a4ed2ae-40f7-4445-8615-a59dccb2905c} because a hard disk 'C:\Users\Jay\VirtualBox VMs\boot2docker-vm\boot2docker-vm.vmdk' with UUID {9a4ed2ae-40f7-4445-8615-a59dccb2905c} already exists.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: VirtualBox
Interface: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

Comment: Thx Larry for your solution, the storage-path is fine. Greetings

Comment: @jaycode I solved the UUID problem by copying the hardisk not in the system explorer, but via VirtualBox ->File->VirtualMediaManager ->Copy

Comment: If you want to specify a specific folder rather than a drive ("f:") you can change the start.sh file in the docker installation folder; however, use something like d:/docker rather than d:\docker (/ rather than \).

Answer (score 18):

1. Stop boot2docker VMs
2. Copy the file `C:\Users\$USERNAME\VirtualBox VMs\boot2docker-vm\boot2docker-vm.vmdk` to drive `D:` (don't delete it just yet).
3. Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager app.
4. Open `File / Virtual Media Manager`.
5. Release and remove boot2docker-vm.vmdk.
6. Back to main panel. Right click on boot2docker-vm, choose Settings.
7. Choose Storage.
8. Add harddisk, then choose boot2docker-vm.vmdk from new location.

Comment: @Larry, correct, it works for existing VM, but if you try to create new VM using `docker-machine create`, new VM will be created on disk C, not D. With my solution every new machine will be on disk D.

Comment: mklink looks interesting, i also noticed the --storage-path in another link, so I added there as well. not tried kitematic

Comment: I can't seem to find .Docker file in C:\ , anywhere else this might be?

Comment: @jaycode, this is a directory, not file. It should be under user home directory at disk C, just updated my answer

Comment: @OleksandrHorobets, I see .boot2docker directory there, but not .docker. Is there another way to find this directory perhaps?

Comment: This is perhaps relevant to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25170003/278191

Comment: @jaycode, perhaps you're using old version of Docker. Could you please clarify versions of Docker/Boot2Docker/docker-machine/docker-toolbox?

Comment: @jaycode, please check this directory (.boot2docker) size and content. Does it contain  vmdk files? Usually disk size could be up to several GBs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95356/discussion-between-jaycode-and-oleksandr-horobets).

Comment: Alright, now, how do I access D:\ drive from boot2docker? check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807891/windows-boot2docker-how-to-add-d-drive-to-be-accessible-from-within-docker

Answer (score 2):

You can store the images outside of the VirtualBox images. You don't have to move the disk.
I like this idea, because the disk by VirtualBox is limited, but if you host in the host, in have the same storage that the host have.

Do it by using VirtualBox shared folder option.
I was able to use a folder in `C:\` drive, for all the data that docker needs.

To do so you have to mount `/var/lib/docker` to a local folder in your host machine.
Set "Auto-Mount", but do not set "Read-Only".

[image]