# Does using a Docker significantly improve the IO and processing speed?

Tags: java, performance, io, docker

I am running a java program that loops through a folder containing zip files, parses each file, does some processing and writes the result to a new file in another folder. I was suggested that I deploy this application on a Docker so that the job can be done more quickly.

I should learn and implement Docker from scratch. Will it provide any substantial IO and processing speed improvements? Is it worth giving a try?

Comment: I am not sure this question is really suited for SO... I'd suggest you just try it and see ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not always, especially if your host is a Windows/Mac machine (which uses a VirtualBox vm, which [includes a *slow* vboxfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33998695/6309))

If your host is already a Linux machine, docker only provides *isolation* (of processes and disk), not really performance improvement (unless you can parallelize your process across several container, like a grid)