# Dockerfile build volume changes not reflected on mounted local folder? (OS X / boot2Docker)

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

Using `docker-compose` I have a *Dockerfile* which builds an environment for a Sails JS app. In my Dockerfile I generate a new Sails scaffold project using `sails new .` (a folder mapped to my local filesystem through docker-compose).

When I run `docker-compose build` everything seems to build successfully. I follow through with a `docker-compose up -d` on my local machine. Then I navigate to the folder that is mapped on the host machine to my local, the folder where on the HOST machine (vm) I generated the new Sails project. I'm *expecting* to see all the files that were generated on the HOST machine during `docker-compose build` sitting there in my local folder. The folder is **BLANK** though? What's up?

My basic *docker-compose* file:

```
node:
  restart: "always"
  build: ./cnt/node
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html
  # DEBUG: conveniently used to keep a container running
  command: /bin/bash -c 'tail -f /dev/null'
```

**NOTE:** ./src is my local folder where my source code will reside. This is mapped to /var/www/html (webroot) on the HOST machine.

Here are the last couple lines from the *Dockerfile* found in *./cnt/node* used to generate the Sails scaffold:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN sails new .
RUN touch test.txt
```

Everything runs successfully when I execute (no errors):

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

When done I `cd src` to examine the source directory where I expected to see my Sails app scaffold, but it's **EMPTY**. What the heck?! There were no errors? What am I missing?

Is it something to do with the *docker-compose* file and that the image I'm buidling is built via `build: ./cnt/node` and LATER I mount the volumes in compose file? Do I need to mount the VOLUMES **first** before I generate the Sails scaffold?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your src folder? Only /Users/... is shared between your host and the VM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33998695/6309

Comment: @VonC yes. Aware of the /Users folder restriction and my src folder is in a subfolder of /Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes are only mounted during run time, `build` is specifically designed to be reproducible, so nothing external is allowed during build.

You'll have to generate the scaffolding on the host by using `docker-compose run node ...`

Comment: Correct answer! Unfortunately `docker-compose run node ...` will generate a new image layer and that's something I want to avoid when generating the scaffold. Resolved my issue by creating a startup script (startup-check.sh) and adding this to the command option in docker-compose: `command: /bin/bash -c '/startup-check.sh &&  [your_standard_container_command]'`

Comment: `docker-compose run node` doesn't create a new image layer, but it does create a new container. You can use `docker-compose run --rm node` to have the container removed immediately after it's done, if that is a concern. Creating new containers is pretty lightweight, so it probably doesn't need to be a concern.  An entrypoint script (as you described) is another common option.