# docker-compose with MongoDb and volumes - doesn't seem to be mounted

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, volumes

I'm trying to run the a `docker-compose` operation which spawns up a `Redis` and `MongoDb` instance and which (should) provide the `MongoDb` instance with a `data-file` from the host pc through the `volumes` specification.

I can successfully boot up the container using the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
   - "6379:6379"
mongo:  
  image: mongo:latest
  volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: --rest
```

assuming it should 'mount' the directory `data/db` of which the `data` dir is next to the `docker-compose.exe` file.

[image]

I can connect to both `Redis` and `MongoDb`, but a simple query on a collection performing a `count()` returns `0` (which should contain data). Which leads me to believe that the mounting of the `volumes` property isn't working.

If I check the file structure on the container I don't see a `/data` folder... **Am I missing something here... Thanks for any lead!**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are showing is the filesystem of [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/), the [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/)-based Linux host which runs the docker daemon.
It is not:

- where your local `./data/db` is ([it should be right beside the `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver))
- where your mounted `/data/db` is: it should be mounted in the mongo container

And that will only works if your files are in `C:\users\...` or `/Users/...`, which is the only host folder mounted by VirtualBox in the Linux VM.

To check if the mount has taken place, do a `docker exec mongo bash`, to open a bash in that container and check `ls /data`.

Comment: ok cool, I was able to see through `Kitematic` that a volume was being mounted, however it was not pointing to the local directory that I specified. The fact that it needs to be in a `c:\users` directory solved it. I moved everything there and now it mounts the correct volume. Too bad that the data can't be loaded which means the container can't be started... (Text file busy: "/data/db/journal/j._0")

Comment: @Ropstah Note that you can mount other folders in boot2docker (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33998695/6309: see also the other answer on that same page)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up. I think I see the error and it is related to permissions on the `/data/db` folder. Somehow the container is unable to write to those files... I'm gonna mark your answer as answer, but hopefully you can point me out where those permissions should be set...

Comment: @Ropstah As an example: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198#issuecomment-171964087, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24986166/6309, or https://github.com/denderello/symfony-docker-example/issues/2#issuecomment-94387272

Comment: Thanks for your link suggestions. However I'm not really sure as to what I need to do to fix it. I cannot start up my container due to the permissions. Only thing I can imagine is doing some `chown` operation on the host (which is Docker right? Not my local pc running the docker VM?) where the `/data/db` folder resides for the `mongodb:mongodb` user/group or something?

Comment: Those links are about setting the right permission through the Dockerfile, before runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101533/discussion-between-ropstah-and-vonc).